# Override get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony-2.7

I am trying to override 
get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser(); function

Currently I am upgrading an outdated symfony 2 codebase from php5 to php7, database mongo.
The system has 3 User classes
User, Staff and Visitor

Staff and Visitor extend User.

And this function used to magically load the relevant class (Staff or Visitor)
`get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

The User class used to have these annotations

```
* @MongoDB\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
* @MongoDB\DiscriminatorMap({"visitor"="Ibtikar\VisitorBundle\Document\Visitor", "staff"="Ibtikar\BackendBundle\Document\Staff"})
```

Which generated problems and was resolved by replacing it with

```
* @MongoDB\InheritanceType("COLLECTION_PER_CLASS")
```

And after that I ran db.collection.aggregate to produce the separate collections

Now I cannot reproduce the desired result for the codebase to run smoothly, what I am trying to do is incrementally upgrade the codebase, so rather than replace the "deprecated" security context, I would like to simply override the `getUser()` function to check which Object to return.

Comment: Why do you need to override it? Maybe we can help you find a workaround

Comment: The getUser should return either a Staff object or a Visitor object, because they have different properties & functions (for example for a Staff member you load their Title, whilst for a visitor you would load the gender in an event listener or service). Currently (after the mentioned above) it returns their parent the User object.